# Versions of the same class with different inheritance

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, include, c-preprocessor

I am working with a mathematical software framework that has two large inheritance trees. This is inspired conceptually: One is for general functions (they inherit from `Func`) and one is for normalized probability density functions (they inherit from `Pdf`).

However, there are some classes that should in principle exist in both hierarchies, for example, a `Gauss` function.

At the moment, there is a `GaussFunc` and a `GaussPdf` class with identical source code implementations, except for the class name and the inheritance from `Func` and `Pdf`, respectively.

I would like to improve this situation by getting rid of the second copy of the source code. I can think of several ways to solve this without messing up the entire inheritance tree, for example using preprocessor macros in combination with `#include` statements, or maybe templates, but I'm not sure as to what is the most advisable thing to do in this situation.

Any suggestion on how to proceed in this situation is highly welcome. However, please note that I cannot restructure the whole software project to avoid this problem a-priori (which is certainly the most sane approach, but not possible within the timeframe of my work and not within the range of things I'm allowed to decide about).

Comment: It sounds like a misuse of inheritance. Hard to tell without the source code.

Comment: it sounds like Pdf should not be separate hierarchy, but rather some adapters (based on template?)  for main hierarchy

Comment: @imreal: what detail of the source code would be interesting? The entire source of the class is ~2000 lines, so pasting it all is a bit beyond the scope of SO I'd assume :-)

Comment: @Swift: Yes, that would have been better. But for the time being, I'm stuck with things being the way they are.

Comment: Something that gives a clue to why inheritance is needed for the class. If it doesn't depend on its parent classes' (`Func` and `pdf`) interface or they also have the same implementation then the problem might be higher on the hierarchy.

Comment: @imreal: `Func` and `Pdf` both inherit from the same base class, and the class only overwrites functions from that base class - but other parts in the framework are required to successfully cast it to `Pdf` or `Func`, depending on the precise use case. However, objects of the `Pdf` and of the `Func` type are not required to be interchangable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just templatize the class you want to inherit from, like this:

```
template<typename Base>
class MetaGauss : public Base
{
    ...
};

typedef MetaGauss<Func> GaussFunc;
typedef MetaGauss<Pdf> GaussPdf;
```

Here is a live demo:

http://ideone.com/XD4E6y